# Excel Macro to get a list of links to files in a specific folder modification

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that allows the user to select a folder, and have the files in that folder listed out as links. However, the list is starting in cell A1, but say, I clicked on cell I5, and I want the list to start at the cell I clicked on. How do I modify the below macro:

```
Sub GetFileNames()

Dim xFSO As Object
Dim xFolder As Object
Dim xFile As Object
Dim xFiDialog As FileDialog
Dim xPath As String
Dim I As Integer
Set xFiDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If xFiDialog.Show = -1 Then
    xPath = xFiDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If
Set xFiDialog = Nothing
If xPath = "" Then Exit Sub
Set xFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xFolder = xFSO.GetFolder(xPath)
For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
    I = I + 1
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(I, 1), xFile.Path, , , xFile.Name
Next
End Sub
```

Thank you so much for your expertise!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feather this in to your macro:

```
Dim curCell As Range
Set curCell = ActiveCell
i = 0
For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(curCell.Row + i, curCell.Column), xFile.Path, , , xFile.Name
    i = i + 1
Next
```

When you run the macro, it will look to see what the active cell is, then use that column and row to start.